# Access the value of a custom knockout binding

Tags: knockout.js

I have a custom knockout binding, e.g. like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.yourBindingName = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor,
                   viewModel, bindingContext)
    {
        // how to access the value-part of the data-bind="name:value" attribute?
    },
};
```

and:

```html
<div data-bind="yourBindingName: someValue"> </div>
```

Is it possible to access the value part of the data-bind attribute (i.e. "someValue" in the above example) from the `init`-function?

---

**Update:** Just to clarify what I mean:

- the data-bind attribute of the `div` has a name and value part, separated by a colon, e.g. "yourBindingName: someValue"
- the name-part specifies which binding to call
- I'd like to access the value-part inside my binding and use it like a parameter

Comment: I've got to be honest here, my question is why do you want to do this?

Comment: Would you mind changing the title to something like "access the name of the binding target" or something other than "value", its very confusing.

Comment: @Tyrsius: I could change the title, but I'm not sure if it would be correct. According to the KO documentation, the second part of the data-bind attribute is called "value".

Comment: @M4N That's true, but its still confusing. An inaccurate but less ambiguous term may still be clearer to someone reading just the question title.

Comment: @M4N Also, does my answer not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then the data sent into the custom binding handler is the valueAccessor, as an observable. So if you want the value, then do:

```
var value = valueAccessor();
```

Comment: I really meant to get the original string-value "someValue" as it is written in the markup. But I guess I have to think about it again - maybe I'm trying to use knockout in a way it's not intended.

Comment: You mean that you want the name of the data property that you are binding to the handler?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you would **ever** want to do this, but here you go:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.reflector = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor,
                   viewModel, bindingContext)
    {
        var reflected;
        var binding = valueAccessor();
        for (var prop in viewModel) {
            if (viewModel[prop] == binding) {
                reflected = prop;
                break;
            }
        }
        ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function(){ return reflected});
    },
};
```

and in [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/J4ZvE/)

Comment: Thanks - I'll try that tomorrow